# Assigning different animationOptions to states on Coffeescript

Tags: animation, properties, prototype, states, framerjs

In the code below, both states have the same animation properties. How can I assign different animation properties to each state?

```
for check in aniCheck
    check.states.add
        one: 
            opacity: 1
            scale: 1
        two:
            scale: 0
    check.states.animationOptions =
        curve:"spring(400,25,50)"
        delay: 2

    iconFav.on Events.Click, ->
        check.states.next("one","two")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a function before the switch event.

```
check.on Events.StateWillSwitch, (oldState, newState) ->
    if newState == 'one'
        check.animationOptions = 
            curve: 'spring(400,25,50)'
            delay: 2
    if newState == 'two'
        check.animationOptions = 
            curve: 'linear'
            delay: 0
```

I'm just learning and build this [Framer JS example](http://share.framerjs.com/yvbi6y1ksntj/) for reference